# Динамическое создание элементов формы

Tags: c#

Недавно перешел с консоли на Forms. Требуется создать приложение, которое будет парсить каталог, и в зависимости о его содержания создавать элемента на форме.
[image: То, что я примерно хочу видеть]

Да, можно сделать это несколькими формами, основное меню - одна форма, элементы генерятся на другой, а второстепенное меню - третья. Убрать у них оформление, и сделать что при перетаскивании одной другие тоже двигались относительно координат перетягиваемой, однако мне кажется, что это костыль.
Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Пока не сформировали себе мировоззрение в рамках WinForms, бросьте его и изучайте WPF

Comment: А так, создавайте панель и помещайте в нее свои элементы, у панели будет полоса прокрутки и ее содержимое будет прокручиваться отдельно от других элементов формы

Comment: Полностью согласен с Андреем, забудьте о WinForms, и начинайте изучать WPF. На первый взгляд сложно, но это полностью оправдывает себя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        Button btn;
        int x = 0;

        private void method(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Hello";
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //создание кнопки
            x += 70;
            btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "b" + x;
            btn.Left = x;
            btn.Top = 100;
            btn.Height = 50;
            btn.Width = 50;
            //размещаем на панели
            panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            //добавляем событие
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(method);

            //добавляем в коллекцию
            buttons.Add(btn);               
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //пролистывание панели
            panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        }
    }
```